# how to access an opened xml file (in browser) with javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

How can i access a xml document, opened in a browser, with javascript?
The loaded xml comes from a webserver and is styled with xsl. i want to access the base xml file with javascript, that can be seen in the page source.

Comment: How do you retrieve that xml from the webserver? using ajax? and what have you done so far to solve the problem?

Comment: The xml file is generated on my server and used as default page. My index.xml is directly served to the browser and contains a xsl stylesheet. i have searched in the developer console, but i'm not sure that i should search...

Comment: I dont understand. Your xml sheet is served as a page? It contains html structure or what?

Comment: The xml contains only data from my server, the browser uses the xsl-stylesheet, defined in the xml file, to produce the html output. if you look at the page source you only see the xml file content.